# Authentication Error (nodejs, mongodb, jwt)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, authentication, jwt

I have this code for the login, and it doesn't authenticate the user, it gives me back the error response I wrote. I tried changing it so the user would stop giving back "null", but nothing is functioning. This is the code:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username
    });
    !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong Credentials");

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );
    const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    OriginalPassword !== req.body.password &&
      res.status(401).json("Wrong Password!");

    const accessToken = jwt.sign({
      id: user._id,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    }, process.env.JWT_SEC,
        {expiresIn:"3d"}
    );

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

    res.status(200).json(...others, accessToken);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

what it gives back is the "Wrong Credentials" string I put; I console logged the req.body.username and it gives me back my username, but the const user just keeps giving back null.
I hope I can find some answer, I'm losing hope already

Comment: Well if `req.body.username` contains a value but `user === null`, the `User` collection does not contain any document with that respective username. Check for typos, check if you are connecting to the correct database, check if there are any documents in that collection ... Other than that: encrypting all passwords in your database with seemingly the same password is a VERY BAD idea ... Read some blogs and tutorials on how to safely store passwords ...

Answer (score -1):

```
const { username, password } = req.body;

try {
  const getUser=user.findOne({username:username})
  if (!getUser) {
    return res.json({err:"User Doesn't Exists"})
  } else {
    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      getUser.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );
    const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    if (user.password === OriginalPassword) {
      const accessToken = jwt.sign({
        id: user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      }, process.env.JWT_SEC, {
        expiresIn: "3d"
      });
 
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

      res.status(200).json(...others, accessToken,{ message: "Logged in 
Successfully"});
    } else {
      return res.json({ err: "Password Doesn't Match" })
    }
  }
} catch(err) {
  return res.json(err)
}
```

Comment: If you care to post an answer, please also care for proper formatting. Furthermore, code only answers are discouraged. Please explain, how your answer solves OP's problem